# Show text under a transparent image

Tags: html, css, gravatar

Let me start with my use-case. I'm implementing a chat where avatars are displayed that are fetched from Gravatar. What I want is to if there is no Gravatar for a user show the initial instead in HTML.

I don't want to go for a solution where I respond to 404's so I thought of this:

- Fetch the Gravatar and have it fallback to a transparent PNG if no avatar is found.
- Under that image, show the initials in HTML.

I can't get it to work. Tried different things but no luck, such as having two absolute div's in a relative div in the same position with the transparent image one on top. This works if there is no image, but as soon as I put up a transparent image, I see no contents from the div 'under it'. Any idea?

```html
<div class="avatar">

<div class="initials" style="
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
height: 50px;
font-size: 22px;
background-color: orange;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 4px;
color: #fff;
font-weight: 500;
z-index: 0;">
    AZ
</div>

<div class="gravatar" style="
width: 50px;
position: absolute;">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7eca53e11beb0074533d7842ce7dd05b?d=blank">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you use the `alt` attribute for the image tag? (`<img src="link" alt="Alt Text" />)

Comment: I See AZ, it seems to be working for me or no?

Comment: What is your target browser?

Comment: @JackStoller +1 or he can also use js to switch out the source if current link does not exist

Comment: Yeah it is working just fine now, I should have checked. Apparently I had a background-color on the image element in the gravatar div. Now all fine!! Thanks!